# If rational $a,b,c$ are such that $a\sqrt[3]{3}+b\sqrt[3]{4}+c\sqrt[3]{5}=0$, then $a=b=c=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Problem:

> Let $a,b,c \in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $a \sqrt[3]{3}+b \sqrt[3]{4}+c\sqrt[3]{5} = 0$.
>   Show that $a=b=c=0$.

Case if $a,b,c \in\mathbb{Z}$ is easy, I solved, but I don't have any idea how can I solve the case when $a,b,c \in\mathbb{Q}$. Maybe with polynomial $f = a \sqrt[3]{3}X^3+b \sqrt[3]{4}X^2+c \sqrt[3]{5}X$ and see $f(1) = 0$, but idk.

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you multiply by the denominators of $a, b, c$?

Comment: Hint: write $a=\frac{a_n}{a_d}$ and similarly $b$ and $c$.

Comment: what you mean guys?

Comment: if you've solved the case $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$, then the case when they are in $\mathbb{Q}$ can be solved by multiplying by a common denominator of $a,b,c$ to make them into $\mathbb{Z}$. The 0 on the right side doesn't change.

Comment: "Case if a,b,c∈Z is easy".  Then just put $a,b,c \in \mathbb Q$ over the same denominator and multiply both sides by that.  You now have a case with only integers.

Answer (score 0):

Assume one of these three is not $0$. Let's say $c$.

So $a=0, b=0,$ and $c= \frac{p}{q},$ where $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$

Our equation $\implies \frac{p}{q}\sqrt[3]{5}=0 \implies \frac{p}{q} = 0$

Since $q \neq 0 \implies p=0$

But then $c=\frac{0}{q} =0.$

(Is there something wrong with what I did?)

Comment: can please share your initiation of assuming two of them to be 0

Comment: That's exactly what I'm asking in the last sentence. If I want to prove the implication ($a=b=c=0$) by contradiction, can I negate this by assuming $a=b=0$ and $c \neq 0$ to arrive at my contradiction?